# React-native-peerjs does not emit steam, why?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, webrtc, peerjs

React-native-peerjs supposed to emit `stream` upon answering call. But we are getting the call and answering it perfectly fine, but no stream gets emitted.
What's wrong here?

We tried to set options like below when we are sending a call:

```
  var options = {
      'constraints': {
        'mandatory': {
          'OfferToReceiveAudio': true,
          'OfferToReceiveVideo': true
        },
        offerToReceiveAudio: 1,
        offerToReceiveVideo: 1,
      }
    }
```

But it still won't work. Here is the entire code:

```
/**
 *
 * @format
 * @flow strict-local
 */

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import type { Node } from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  Dimensions,
  useColorScheme,
  View,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text
} from 'react-native';

import { Colors } from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';
import Peer from 'react-native-peerjs';
import { RTCView, mediaDevices } from 'react-native-webrtc';


const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');

const App: () => Node = () => {
  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';

  const backgroundStyle = {
    backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.darker : Colors.lighter,
    flex: 1,
  };
  const [remotePeerId, setRemotePeerId] = useState('');
  const [ongoin, setOngoin] = useState(undefined);
  const [localPeer] = useState(() => new Peer()); // using peer cloud
  const [localStream, setLocalStream] = useState();
  const [remoteStreams, setRemoteStreams] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Local peer is opening ...');

    let isFront = true;
    mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(sourceInfos => {
      let videoSourceId;
      for (let i = 0; i < sourceInfos.length; i++) {
        const sourceInfo = sourceInfos[i];
        if (
          sourceInfo.kind == 'videoinput' &&
          sourceInfo.facing == (isFront ? 'front' : 'environment')
        ) {
          videoSourceId = sourceInfo.deviceId;
        }
      }
      mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({
          audio: true,
          video: {
            mandatory: {
              minFrameRate: 30,
            },
            facingMode: isFront ? 'user' : 'environment',
            optional: videoSourceId ? [{ sourceId: videoSourceId }] : [],
          },
        })
        .then(stream => {
          setLocalStream(stream);
          localPeer.on('open', peerId => {
            console.log('Local peer is opened with Id = ' + peerId);

            localPeer.on('call', call => {
              console.log('Local peer receives incoming call');

              call.answer(stream); // answring call should emit 'stream', but won't
              

              call?.on('stream', remoteStream => {
                console.log('Local peer receives stream from remote peer');

                setRemoteStreams([remoteStream, remoteStream, remoteStream]);
              });
            });

         
          });
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    });

    return () => {
      if (localPeer) {
        localPeer.destroy();
        console.log('Local peer is destroyed');
      }
    };
  }, []);


  const handleCallPress = () => {
    console.log("CURRENT STREAM");

    var options = {
      'constraints': {
        'mandatory': {
          'OfferToReceiveAudio': true,
          'OfferToReceiveVideo': true
        },
        offerToReceiveAudio: 1,
        offerToReceiveVideo: 1,
      }
    }

    const outgoingCall = localPeer.call(remotePeerId, localStream, options);



      setOngoin(outgoingCall); 
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!ongoin) return;
    console.log("Running steam");
    
    ongoin.on('stream', (remoteStream) => {
      console.log('Local peer receives stream from remote peer');
      setRemoteStreams([remoteStream, remoteStream, remoteStream]);
    });

  }, [ongoin]);


  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={backgroundStyle}>
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 0.7,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
          }}>
          {localStream ? (
            <RTCView
              streamURL={localStream.toURL()}
              style={{
                width: width * 0.9 - 8,
                height: 200,
              }}
            />
          ) : null}
        </View>
        <ScrollView
          horizontal
          style={{ flex: 0.8 }}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
          <>
            {remoteStreams ? (
              remoteStreams.length > 0 ? (
                <>
                  {remoteStreams.map((stream, index) => {
                    return (
                      <View
                        key={index}
                        style={{
                          width: width * 0.9,
                          marginRight: 8,
                          justifyContent: 'center',
                          alignItems: 'center',
                        }}>
                        <RTCView
                          streamURL={stream.toURL()}
                          style={{
                            width: width * 0.9 - 8,
                            height: 300,
                          }}
                        />
                      </View>
                    );
                  })}
                </>
              ) : null
            ) : null}
          </>
        </ScrollView>
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 0.5,
          }}></View>
      </View>


      <View style={{ flex: 0.5, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <TextInput
          style={{
            height: 40,
            borderColor: 'gray',
            borderWidth: 1,
            padding: 8,
            marginBottom: 16,
            width: width * 0.8,
            borderRadius: 8,
          }}
          placeholder="Enter Remote Peer ID"
          onChangeText={(text) => setRemotePeerId(text)}
          value={remotePeerId}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => handleCallPress()}
          style={{
            backgroundColor: '#4CAF50',
            padding: 10,
            borderRadius: 8,
          }}>
          <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Initiate Call</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default App;
```